# Can I use "or" between two synonyms?

Tags: synonyms

For example, can I say the following?

*There are three styles or paradigms to program in Java.*

My intention is to be extra sure that the reader understands what I am talking about. The more appropriate word would be "paradigm", but I am also adding its synonym - style so that if the reader doesn't understand "paradigm" they will hopefully understand the word "style".

Comment: Yes, you may do this.

Comment: That's one way to indicate synonyms intended as 'exact synonyms', but is unsatisfactory as the [A or B] reading is just as possible as the [A or A']. Sometimes, a slash is a convenient 'fuzzy connector' (intentionally open to interpretation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. What you have written is grammatically correct. Even the closet synonyms can convey subtly different meanings. Thus, combining them, as you have done, can more accurately capture what you wish to convey and add clarity for the reader.

I would add that 'paradigm' and 'style' are not necessarily synonyms. 'Paradigm' has the sense of a viewpoint that is shared by a cohort whereas 'style' is more individual. Using both gives the sense that one can follow a certain prescribed approach in their writing of Java code whilst still retaining some individuality of expression. If that is your intention then you have achieved it.

Comment: Thank you so much! It seems like "style" is not what I want here. Would "way" be more appropriate than "style"?

Comment: @multigoodverse I'm not sure 'way' really works and I think style is fine. You could also use 'approach', 'perspective', 'outlook' or synonyms of those.

Comment: How does someone not au fait with terminology/concepts hereabouts (as OP themself  concedes they are) distinguish whether the 'synonym' or the 'alternative' meaning is intended? Conformity to Gricean maxims is at least as necessary than grammaticality. The one in question, _avoid ambiguity_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth, I don't understand your English, sorry. I would recommend you use simpler words so that non-native speakers can understand you as well.

Comment: ELU is aimed at linguists, multigoodverse. 'There are three styles or paradigms to program in Java.' might mean (1) 'There are three _styles_ (aka _paradigms_) to program in Java.' as you require. But it might also mean (3) 'There are three styles (or alternatively three paradigms) to program in Java.' (ie you can address the issue in two ways). It can also have the fuzzier sense (2) 'There are three _styles_ (or should one say  _paradigms_?  It's hard to choose the word that best fits) to program in Java.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth The Gricean maxim of manner would seem most relevant here.

Comment: I hate editing these things and leaving relicts. _At least as necessary than_? I'd like 'intermediate comments' with better formatting and editing options. // Yes, Gricean maxim of manner: Avoid (1) obscurity of expression (2) ambiguity (3) unnecessary prolixity (4) disorganisation. Unfortunately, I've not come across a term for sub-maxims, so condensed. Probably (3') unhelpful degree of compression.